# Adding Images to an ASP .Net Chart Control

Tags: asp.net, charts

I'm not sure if I titled the question correctly so it would be better if I explained what I'm trying to do. I am using the ASP .Net Chart Control to create a line chart showing numbers of trouble calls based on date. What I would like to do is implement a way of annotating the chart with data whereas if there was a spike in trouble calls a line, or asterisk, etc would direct the viewer to "read notes below for an explanation for why the numbers spiked here".

From the samples for the chart control there is a way you can add a bitmap to the chart, however I don't see how that will be effective here because the explanations will come dynamically from a database.

If anyone's done something like this or has some guidance I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that that's possible with an ASP.NET Chart control. Based on your explanation, it sounds like you could add the notes below the chart for a pretty reasonable solution. Just reference the spikes or anomalies by writing the proper date next to each note.